# How to send a "password reset" email on button click without using firebase in kotlin?

Tags: email, android-studio, onclick, kotlin

I have an activity called "password reset activity", and a button called "send" and an edittext to ask for user's input(their email address) so i can automatically send them an email with a link for them to reset/recover their password when they click the button.  All the solutions i found are using firebase, i was wondering can i do it without using firebase? or can i just use this one feature of firebase without setting up all the other features (eg. user login information ..) and the language im using is kotlin
thank you!